# Verificar e alterar os 3 primeiros caracteres de uma string?

Tags: android

Por exemplo, uma string com telefone +5531984892883.
Gostaria de verificar se os 3 primeiros caracteres são iguais a +55. Se eles forem iguais a +55, substituí-los por 0 (zero).
Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: O problema disso aí é que se o código do pais é exatamente 5 e logo depois vir o número começado com 5, seu programa vai pro saco. heuhe;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use o método [`replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)):

```
final String telefone = "+5531984892883";
final String outroTelefone = "31984892883";

System.out.println("Telefone :" + telefone);
System.out.println("Telefone sem o codigo :" + telefone.replace("+55", "0"));
System.out.println();

System.out.println("Outro telefone :" + outroTelefone);
System.out.println("Outro telefone sem o codigo :" + outroTelefone.replace("+55", "0"));
```

Saída:

```
Telefone :+5531984892883
Telefone sem o codigo :031984892883

Outro telefone :31984892883
Outro telefone sem o codigo :31984892883
```

Exemplo online [aqui](https://repl.it/JEPf/0).

Comment: É necessário a verificação antes, para substituir. Pois pode não haver estes caracteres, há algum problema em não fazer a verificação?

Comment: @HenriqueMendes não é necessário. Veja a resposta atualizada